# htaccess redirect all html except one subfolder to new url in shared environment

Tags: .htaccess

Within a contao-cms installation I am trying to redirect(301) all pages containing `/de/` and ending on `.html` to a new domain except all pages of one subfolder `/de/dont-redirect-me`.

How can I adjust the following rule to match aboves requirements?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/de/(.*)$ http://www.new-server.de/$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your rule needs to match URLs ending with `.html`
2. Use a **negative lookahead** to skip redirection when there is `dont-redirect-me` after `/de/`:

You can use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/de/(?!dont-redirect-me)(.+\.html)$ http://www.new-server.de/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Htaccess rules are read from top to bottom so you have to put first the rule with the subfolder and then the other rule.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^de/dont-redirect-me/(.*)$ http://www.this-server.de/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^de/(.*)$ http://www.new-server.de/$1
```